# Retrieve the 1st occurrence of a sub string in a list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list that contains multiple strings as follows:

```
ls= ['CN=text_1 ,CN =Users,OU=text_12,DC=eample,DC=com', 'CN=text_3433,CN=users,OU=text4,DC=example,DC=com']
```

Now I want to get a list that should contain only the 1st occurrence of `CN=`. So the resultant list should look like:

```
ls_f = ['text_1','text_3433']
```

I am trying below:

```
cn_txt = [i[3:10] for  i in ls]
```

Clearly, this would not work.
I was trying to ascertain the position index of `CN=` using a list comprehension

```
cn = [i.find('CN=') for i in ls] #---getting 0
```

And then using that index number to fetch the substring right after `CN=` till the 1st `,`. But no luck.

Any clue how to get the correct approach?

PS: regex can be looked upon.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to split the string at `,` and then take the first part after `CN=` -

```
cn = [i.split(',')[0][3:].strip() for i in ls if i.startswith('CN=')]
```

Here we are checking if the string starts with `CN=`, if it does, split the string at `,` and then from the first part, extract the part after `CN=`

**Output:**

```
['text_1', 'text_3433']
```